# Error installing dependencies when deploying to Heroku

Tags: php, symfony, heroku, doctrine-orm, heroku-cli

I am trying deploy my Symfony App to Heroku, but when I run the command `git push heroku master` I get the error:

> ***Uncaught Error: Class 'Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle' not found in /tmp/build_808fab60090f288d282076c72569d1ad/app/AppKernel.php:19***

The error log:

```
Generating optimized autoload files 
remote: > Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters 
remote: Creating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file 
remote: > Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap 
remote: > Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache 
remote: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle' not found in /tmp/build_808fab60090f288d282076c72569d1ad/app/AppKernel.php:19 
remote: Stack trace: 
remote: #0 /tmp/build_808fab60090f288d282076c72569d1ad/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(450): AppKernel->registerBundles() 
remote: #1 /tmp/build_808fab60090f288d282076c72569d1ad/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(116): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles() 
remote: #2 /tmp/build_808fab60090f288d282076c72569d1ad/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php(137): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() 
remote: #3 /tmp/build_808fab60090f288d282076c72569d1ad/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php(124): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->registerCommands() 
remote: #4 /tmp/build_808fab60090f288d282076c72569d1ad/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(90): Symfony\Bundle\Framewor in /tmp/build_808fab60090f288d282076c72569d1ad/app/AppKernel.php on line 19 
remote: Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the symfony-scripts event terminated with an exception 
remote: 
remote: 
remote: [RuntimeException] 
remote: An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear —no-warmup'" command: 
remote: 
remote: 
remote: 
remote: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle' not found in /tmp/build_808fab60090f288d282076c72569d1ad/app/AppKernel.php:19 
remote: Stack trace: 
remote: #0 /tmp/build_808fab60090f288d282076c72569d1ad/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(450): AppKernel->registerBundles() 
remote: #1 /tmp/build_808fab60090f288d282076c72569d1ad/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(116): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles() 
remote: #2 /tmp/build_808fab60090f288d282076c72569d1ad/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php(137): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() 
remote: #3 /tmp/build_808fab60090f288d282076c72569d1ad/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php(124): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->registerCommands() 
remote: #4 /tmp/build_808fab60090f288d282076c72569d1ad/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(90): Symfony\Bundle\Framewor in /tmp/build_808fab60090f288d282076c72569d1ad/app/AppKernel.php on line 19 
remote: 
remote: 
remote: install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]... 
remote: 
remote: ! WARNING: There was a class not found error in your code 
remote: 
remote: ! ERROR: Dependency installation failed!
```

My `AppKernel::registerBundles()`

```php
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle(),
            new Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Bundle\DoctrineBehaviorsBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle(),
            new Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle(),
        ];

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();

            if ('dev' === $this->getEnvironment()) {
                $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
                $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle();
            }
        }

        return $bundles;
    }
```

composer.json ("require" blocks)

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.3",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "knplabs/doctrine-behaviors": "^1.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.3.*",
        "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
    }
}
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: @yivi yes , thanks a lot, it works. But now i get another error like:

```
PHP Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /tmp/build_c1c44af237acd11b7e49f6c98f7d82b5/vendor/symfony/monolog-bundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php on line 654
```

Comment: That's a different issue, unrelated to this one. You may need to ask a new question, but it's probably better if you spend some time testing and resarching so your question has all the necessary details. If my answer solved **this** issue, remember that you can _accept_ it. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

You have installed "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle" for development:

```
"require-dev": {
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
    },
```

But are trying to use it in production.

When you deploy your app heroku is installing the composer dependencies using the `--no-dev` flag, which skips the packages declared in `require-dev`.

When the application attempts to run `AppKernel::registerBundles()`, it will try to instantiate `Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle`, but that package is not installed.

Your should delete your line 19 (`new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle(),`) and add it somewhere in the following block:

```php
if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle();
           // ^^^^^ this line here
```

This is checking that the environment is either `dev` or `test`, and only trying to use these packages if on these environments.